# Parse specific table to array of strings Jsoup

Tags: android, html, kotlin, jsoup

i have this, rather complex html I want to parse using JSoup. I have tried several things, but none is working. Basically, I wanted to get the second table, and read all rows and append it to string.

**What I have tried**

```
val document = Jsoup.parse(it.data)

                val tableElements = document.select("table:eq(2) > tbody")
                for (element in tableElements) {
                    val data = element.select("td")
                    try {
                        Timber.i("${data[0].select("small").text()} : ${data[1].select("small").text()}")
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                    }
                }
```

**What part I want to extract**

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="">
      <td class="odsazena" align="left"><small>User's identification number: </small></td>
      <td class="odsazena" align="left"><small>34565</small></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td class="odsazena" align="left"><small>Study programme: </small></td>
      <td class="odsazena" align="left"><small>Informatics</small></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td class="odsazena" align="left"><small>Type of study: </small></td>
      <td class="odsazena" align="left"><small>Bachelor</small></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td class="odsazena" align="left"><small>Form of study: </small></td>
      <td class="odsazena" align="left"><small>full-time, attendance method</small></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td class="odsazena" align="left"><small>Standard length of study: </small></td>
      <td class="odsazena" align="left"><small>3</small></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td class="odsazena" align="left"><small>Number of credits required to complete your study: </small></td>
      <td class="odsazena" align="left"><small>180</small></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td class="odsazena" align="left"><small>Number of credits enrolled for the whole study: </small></td>
      <td class="odsazena" align="left"><small>120</small></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td class="odsazena" align="left"><small>Number of credits obtained during your whole course of study: </small></td>
      <td class="odsazena" align="left"><small>90</small></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td class="odsazena" align="left"><small>Your prospective academic degree: </small></td>
      <td class="odsazena" align="left"><small>Bc.</small></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td class="odsazena" align="left"><small>Beginning of study: </small></td>
      <td class="odsazena" align="left"><small>09/01/2017</small></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td class="odsazena" align="left"><small>Resolution of admission: </small></td>
      <td class="odsazena" align="left"><small>Admitted without the entrance exam</small></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td class="odsazena" align="left"><small>Progress of study: </small></td>
      <td class="odsazena" align="left"><small>enrolled</small></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td class="odsazena" align="left"><small>Mode of completion: </small></td>
      <td class="odsazena" align="left"><small><i>not stated</i></small></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td class="odsazena" align="left"><small>Current financing: </small></td>
      <td class="odsazena" align="left"><small>study fully financed from ME SK</small></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td class="odsazena" align="left"><small>Final thesis topic: </small></td>
      <td class="odsazena" align="left"><small><i>not stated</i></small></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td class="odsazena" align="left"><small>Final thesis supervisor: </small></td>
      <td class="odsazena" align="left"><small><i>not stated</i></small></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td class="odsazena" align="left"><small>Language of study: </small></td>
      <td class="odsazena" align="left"><small>Slovak</small></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td class="odsazena" align="left"><small>Card number:</small></td>
      <td class="odsazena" align="left"><small>123456</small></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And now, what is the problem exactly? Well from what I've tried, the code does not even let me print the stuff I want, and in the current state as it is it will just skip the for cycle. What I wanted to achieve is that I wanted to get to second table "table:eq(2)" and get elements inside "tbody"

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should select the "tr" elements as well and iterate over them as looks like you are iteratin over "tbody". This is a solution in Java, as I don't know Kotlin syntax, but maybe it helps:

```
Elements tableElements = doc.select("table").get(1).select("tbody").select("tr");
for (Element element : tableElements) {
    Elements data = element.select("td");
    System.out.println(data.select("small").first().text() +" : "
    + data.select("small").last().text());  
}
```

Comment: Sure I will try that. But, how can I select this table if it's second in the document ?

Comment: You can use `.get(index)` so you can select the "index" appearance of the tag <table> (the first is 0). I have modified my answer adding it in the right place. Hope it helps.

Comment: Sure and one last thing, do I have to skip write also elements in which this tab is nested ?

Comment: Maybe your code is ok only changing the `eq(2)` for `eq(1)`

Comment: If you use the table selector you don't need to take into account any parent tag in which the table is included, as long as it is not another table. Usually, the HTML as id attributes that are unique for each of the elements, so they are useful for searching elements, as well (not in this case).

Comment: Did you get an error or it is not giving any result?

Answer (score 0):

This is java code to do what you want. 
You can apply selector on elements.

```
@Test
public void selectSecondTable() {

    String html = "" +
            "<table></table>" +
            "<table>\n" +
            "  <tbody>\n" +
            "    <tr class=\"\">\n" +
            "      <td class=\"odsazena\" align=\"left\"><small>User's identification number: </small></td>\n" +
            "      <td class=\"odsazena\" align=\"left\"><small>34565</small></td>\n" +
            "    </tr>\n" +
            "  </tbody>\n" +
            "</table>";

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    //select tr from second table in document:
    for (Element e : doc.select("table:eq(1) tr")) {
        //for each table row select text from small tag and print to console:
        System.out.println(e.select("small").text());
    }

}
```

Comment: Elements are indexed starting from 0, so to select second table use table:eq(1)